# what is a good technology compatible with javato add simple field boxes in HTML?

Tags: java, html, web-services, user-interface

I have a Web Service and I'm trying to add a simple Web User interface with the ability of adding some text and uploading file. what is the simplest and easiest one to use and compatible with Java. I'm using eclipse to develop my application.

I don't need a lot of support I just want it to be easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend wicket (http://wicket.apache.org/) you won't have licence restrictions (it's an Apache licence) and it's a time resistent solution: JSF are too complex for simple use cases, and Struts is quite as complicated but a rather old technology. GWT is too complex and time conuming for small projects.

You can naturally use bare Servlets or JSPs if you're really in very simple use cases.

Best Regards,
Zied Hamdi
http://1vu.fr